# Charge distribution on the internal surface of a thin conducting spherical shell with a small hole

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

We have a thin conducting spherical shell with a small hole drilled in it. Now, some charge is given to the shell. Will there be any Charge distributed on the internal surface of the shell?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, **half** the charge on the part of the shell which was removed is redistributed to the inner surface of the shell and half is redistributed on the outer surface.

---

The electric field at the outer surface of a uniformly charged spherical shell is the same as from a point charge : $E=\frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 R^2}=\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}$ where $\sigma=Q/A$ is the surface charge density of the whole shell and $Q, A$ are its total charge and total surface area.  Inside the shell the electric field is $0$ (see **Newton's Shell Theorem**, which applies for spherically symmetric mass or charge distributions).

This electric field $E$ is made up of 2 components : that $E_1$ due to the local charge on a disk occupying the orifice and that $E_2$ due to the rest of the spherical shell : $E=E_1+E_2$.

[image]

The electric field due to the charge on the disk is $E_1=\pm \frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon}$. It points both inwards and outwards. The electric field $E_2$ from the rest of the shell points only outwards, as from a point charge located at the centre of the sphere.

Inside the shell $E_1$and $E_2$ point in opposite directions, so the total electric field inside the shell is zero : $E_2+E_1=0$. This means that $E_2=-E_1=\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}$. Outside the shell both components $E_1, E_2$ point in the same direction and add up to $E=\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}$.

If the disk is removed from the spherical shell, leaving a small orifice, the electric field through this orifice is $E_2=+\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}$ outwards. All of the field lines passing through the orifice must start on charges on the inner surface of the spherical shell. Using a gaussian surface 
between the inner and outer surfaces of the spherical shell, the flux through this surface is $aE_2$ so the charge enclosed (ie on the inner surface of the sphell) is $$q=\epsilon_0 aE_2=\epsilon_0 a \frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}=\frac{a}{A}\frac{Q}{2}$$ This means that **half** the charge which would have been on the disk has redistributed to the inner surface and half to the outer surface of the spherical shell.

Source : [Conducting Spherical Shell with a Circular Orifice](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/449d/c7da28170745b7511bde5df0a14c8dc281c2.pdf)